# Difference Between Ajax Calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can someone please tell what the difference between these two ajax calls is?:

```
function DownTimeStop(data) {
    Hesto.Ajax.Get({
        query: ADD_DOWNTIME_STOP
        , data: Hesto.Ajax.BuildQueryString(data)
        , success: ShowEndData
        , error: Hesto.Ajax.ErrorHandler
    });
}
```

and this function call

```
function DownTimeStop(){
    $.ajax({
        url: ADD_DOWNTIME_STOP,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: ShowEndData,
        error: Hesto.Ajax.ErrorHandler
    });
}
```

Comment: dataType: 'json' is the most important Change. And in the second you aren't sending the data.

Comment: What's Hesto? Also, `$.ajax()` does not look like it is passing in any request data

Comment: Also, might be worth looking inside `Hesto.Ajax.BuildQueryString()` function to see what its doing. Probably just serializing.

Comment: @techfoobar: which would be something I'd advice against. Not that it doesn't work, but apparently it doesn't escape characters like é or à (it turns them into a regular e or a). If you keep your data as JSON, it does escape the characters properly. If accented characters are a possibility; that is. Otherwise, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: danx for all your comments